# unable to save changes in jupyter notebook on DSX

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience, dsx

Occasionally, I'm unable to save changes to my notebook in DSX.  I believe this is because my session has timed out.

How can I prevent my changes from being lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that tends to work best for me is to go the **File** menu and select **Download as** and then choose one of the options.

The download attempts to open a new window which will re-establish your session.  You should now be able to save the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

The session expires after 1 hour of inactivity (no API requests to the notebook server). When you are editing the notebook, it is saved every two minutes. When the session is expired you could reload the notebook page and continue working with the notebook. If the service was not deactivated then the same kernel will be connected.

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  The problem is that many times you don't spot that the session has expired and you continue working on the notebook.  If you reload your notebook at this point, you will lose your changes.